# Div wont remain expanded when I hover over it

Tags: html, css, hover, division

So I'm designing this graphic heavy website and I wanted to have this box display when you hover over the image that tells you more about the image you're looking at, with a link if you wanted more information. I just realized that when you move your mouse to this new div, it collapses. I don't understand why, or how to make it stop.

`Here is a` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgqv4per/)

Comment: :hover only works when the cursor is on the image

Comment: you need to use jquery or javascript to make it work

Comment: because you aren't hovering over the image anymore

Comment: @Sushil no you don't need js. you need to atttach the `:hover` to the wrapping `<div />`

Comment: @zgood - Actually, there's more in this div than just the image and hidden div. There's also a table with a bit more information, it just didn't have anything to do with my problem, so I didn't include it.

Comment: @ShirleyDodson You can try my answer below... it still may work. If not then JavaScript may be needed like mentioned by Sushil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your wrapping `<div>` a class like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqmbvn7v/).

The key is this css style:

```
.wrapper:hover #b-image-info {
    display: block;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This should help:

```
.wrapper:hover * { display:none;}
.warpper:hover #b-image, .warpper:hover #b-image-info { display: block; }
```

Comment: Well, this fixes my problem, but I have more in this div and I only want the box to display when you hover over the image. BUT! Maybe I can put the image into it's own wrapping div and then follow your suggestion . . . let me try.

Comment: @ShirleyDodson or you could create another style like this: `.wrapper:hover #another-div, .wrapper #something-else { display: none; }`

Comment: Or maybe this is cleaner: `.wrapper:hover * { display:none; } .wrapper:hover #b-image, .warpper:hover #b-image-info { display:block; }`

Answer (score 0):

Well just in case you want to do with js/jquery. You could do something like this.
When hovered get the image info and change its display property.

```
$("#b-image").hover(function(){
   $("#b-image-info").css("display", "block");
}, function(){
    //nothing
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/jq3xkm6y/